# MySQL - IN (array) ORDER BY original

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do a search like this:

`SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id IN (4, 5, 1)`

but, the result is ordered by ID

```
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+-------+------------+--------+
| id | question                                                                                   | answer                     | notes | difficulty | toggle |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+-------+------------+--------+
|  1 | VAR is much talked about in football - what does VAR stand for?                            | Video Assistant Referee    |       | Medium     |      1 |
|  4 | Which large construction company has gone into receivership with debts of Â£1.5 billion?   | Carillion                  |       | Easy       |      0 |
|  5 | What does PFI stand for in PFI contracts?                                                  | Private Finance Initiative |       | Easy       |      1 |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+-------+------------+--------+
```

however, i need the results in the order of the array. I've found somewhere the following:

`SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id IN (4, 5, 1) ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(id, '4, 5, 1');`

which kinda works, but returns it in reverse:

```
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+-------+------------+--------+
| id | question                                                                                   | answer                     | notes | difficulty | toggle |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+-------+------------+--------+
|  1 | VAR is much talked about in football - what does VAR stand for?                            | Video Assistant Referee    |       | Medium     |      1 |
|  5 | What does PFI stand for in PFI contracts?                                                  | Private Finance Initiative |       | Easy       |      1 |
|  4 | Which large construction company has gone into receivership with debts of Â£1.5 billion?   | Carillion                  |       | Easy       |      0 |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+-------+------------+--------+
```

Then, the proposed solution was to add `DESC` at the end

`SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id IN (4, 5, 1) ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(id, '4, 5, 1') desc;`

which return this, which i don't get at all

```
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+-------+------------+--------+
| id | question                                                                                   | answer                     | notes | difficulty | toggle |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+-------+------------+--------+
|  4 | Which large construction company has gone into receivership with debts of Â£1.5 billion?   | Carillion                  |       | Easy       |      0 |
|  1 | VAR is much talked about in football - what does VAR stand for?                            | Video Assistant Referee    |       | Medium     |      1 |
|  5 | What does PFI stand for in PFI contracts?                                                  | Private Finance Initiative |       | Easy       |      1 |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+-------+------------+--------+
```

Why is 4, 1, 5 and not 4, 5, 1? How do I make it return 4, 5, 1?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an `ORDER BY FIELD()` or an `ORDER BY CASE WHEN...`

In your case the first one is probably the most simpler

```
SELECT * 
FROM questions 
WHERE id IN (4, 5, 1) 
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 4, 5, 1)
```

[SQLfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/923a0/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
drop table if exists t;

create table t(id int, question varchar(100));

insert into t values                 
(  1 , 'VAR is much talked about in football - what does VAR stand for?'                            ),
(  4 , 'Which large construction company has gone into receivership with debts of Â£1.5 billion?'   ),
(  5 , 'What does PFI stand for in PFI contracts?'   ); 

select * 
from t
order by case when id = 4 then 1
                  when id = 1 then 2
                  else 3
            end;

+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | question                                                                                 |
+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    4 | Which large construction company has gone into receivership with debts of Â£1.5 billion? |
|    1 | VAR is much talked about in football - what does VAR stand for?                          |
|    5 | What does PFI stand for in PFI contracts?                                                |
+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```